# Select columns into variables, along with other columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In a MYSQL Stored-Procedure I need to select both the table columns, **and** select columns into variables for further use within that procedure.

Below, a simplified version of the stored-procedure.

```
DECLARE pUSR_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE pPRJ_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE pUSR_LAN_ID BIGINT;

SELECT USR_ID, USR_Login, USR_Password, USR_Archived, USR_Deleted, 
  USR_ID, USR_PRJ_ID, USR_LAN_ID INTO pUSR_ID, pPRJ_ID, pUSR_LAN_ID
FROM tblUsers
WHERE USR_Login = 'foobar';
```

When I execute the above stored-procedure, I get the following error message, which makes sense.

`Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

So, I placed the variables first, and the other columns after the variables.

```
SELECT USR_ID, USR_PRJ_ID, USR_LAN_ID INTO pUSR_ID, pPRJ_ID, pUSR_LAN_ID,
  USR_ID, USR_Login, USR_Password, USR_FullName, USR_IsProjectAdmin, USR_Archived,
  USR_Deleted
```

Executing this returns: `Error 1327: Undeclared variable: USR_ID`. I understand why I am getting the error.

What I don't understand is how I can both select the table columns **and** select certain columns into variables in the same statement?

Comment: to select into variables, you have to use `select ... into ...`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Looks like someone hasn't been reading the question properly.

Comment: Your Select/Into need to have the same number of columns/variables.

Comment: @chris What you're saying is that I will need to create variables that I won't use, in order to have the same amount of columns as variables?

Comment: I'm not getting your goal: do you want to have a single `SELECT` statement where you both initialize the variables you have declared *and* get the results, which are other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*
DECLARE pUSR_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE pPRJ_ID BIGINT;
DECLARE pUSR_LAN_ID BIGINT;
*/ /*no need to declare*/


SELECT 
@pUSR_ID:=USR_ID, 
USR_Login, 
USR_Password, 
USR_Archived, 
USR_Deleted, 
USR_ID, 
@pPRJ_ID:=USR_PRJ_ID, 
@pUSR_LAN_ID:=USR_LAN_ID 
FROM tblUsers
WHERE USR_Login = 'foobar';
```